# One to Many mapping between three entities in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot

I want to build a Many to One relation between three entities i.e. User to Board(Many) & Board to Cards(Many) i.e. a user can have many boards and a board can have many cards. I am using Spring JPA and to create the db schema automatically . I've set the properties correctly but I am not able to connect them properly so that db  schema can be build automatically . Here are my model classes , Please help :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy = "username" , targetEntity = Board.class)
    private List<Board> boards;

}
```

Board class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "board")
public class Board {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "boardid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "boardname")
    private String boardname;

    @Column(name = "boardcreationdate")
    private DateTime boardCreationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "userid")
    private User username;

    @OneToMany(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy = "boardname" , targetEntity = Board.class)
    private Set<Card> cards;

}
```

Card class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cardid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cardName")
    private String cardName;

    @Column(name = "cardcreationdate")
    private DateTime cardCreationDate;

    @Column(name = "cardtimeondone")
    private DateTime cardTimeOnDone;

    @Column(name = "cardlife")
    private DateTime cardLife;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boardid", referencedColumnName = "boardid")
    private Board boardname;

}
```

Here is the application.properties file with some properties .

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=34000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=55000
spring.datasource.max-wait=28800000
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

It is creating schema but giving errors as below : -

```
        2016-06-20 15:12:37.288 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table board 
        drop 
        foreign key FKbon6omt9qov9iduumkuj117xw
2016-06-20 15:12:37.357 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table board 
        drop 
        foreign key FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3
2016-06-20 15:12:37.386  WARN 8772 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    alter table board 
        drop 
        foreign key FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    alter table board 
        drop 
        foreign key FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:327) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:229) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1182) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1171) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at com.causecode.challenge.TrellocardlifeApplication.main(TrellocardlifeApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Can't DROP 'FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3'; check that column/key exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted

2016-06-20 15:12:37.392 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table card 
        drop 
        foreign key FKgicrq63fj0nx3bh6wlncf235i
2016-06-20 15:12:37.424 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    drop table if exists board
2016-06-20 15:12:37.437 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    drop table if exists card
2016-06-20 15:12:37.448 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    drop table if exists user
2016-06-20 15:12:37.468 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table board (
        boardid bigint not null auto_increment,
        boardcreationdate tinyblob,
        boardname varchar(255),
        userid bigint,
        primary key (boardid)
    )
2016-06-20 15:12:37.539 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table card (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        cardcreationdate tinyblob,
        cardlife tinyblob,
        card_name varchar(255),
        cardtimeondone tinyblob,
        boardid bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )
2016-06-20 15:12:37.600 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table user (
        userid bigint not null auto_increment,
        password varchar(255),
        username varchar(255),
        primary key (userid)
    )
2016-06-20 15:12:37.631 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table board 
        add constraint FKbon6omt9qov9iduumkuj117xw 
        foreign key (userid) 
        references user (userid)
2016-06-20 15:12:37.752 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table board 
        add constraint FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3 
        foreign key (boardname) 
        references board (boardid)
2016-06-20 15:12:37.812  WARN 8772 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    alter table board 
        add constraint FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3 
        foreign key (boardname) 
        references board (boardid)]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    alter table board 
        add constraint FKcefyg893q4c26nvw7uus84ts3 
        foreign key (boardname) 
        references board (boardid)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:408) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:165) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:134) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:120) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:148) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) [hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) [spring-orm-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.3.0.RC2.jar:4.3.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1182) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1171) [spring-boot-1.4.0.M3.jar:1.4.0.M3]
    at com.causecode.challenge.TrellocardlifeApplication.main(TrellocardlifeApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2016-06-20 15:12:37.814 DEBUG 8772 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    alter table card 
        add constraint FKgicrq63fj0nx3bh6wlncf235i 
        foreign key (boardid) 
        references board (boardid)
2016-06-20 15:12:37.900  INFO 8772 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@329bad59'
2016-06-20 15:12:37.954  INFO 8772 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-06-20 15:12:39.191  INFO 8772 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-06-20 15:12:39.200  INFO 8772 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2016-06-20 15:12:39.305  INFO 8772 --- [           main] c.c.challenge.TrellocardlifeApplication  : Started TrellocardlifeApplication in 8.172 seconds (JVM running for 8.914)
2016-06-20 15:12:39.306  INFO 8772 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7fad8c79: startup date [Mon Jun 20 15:12:31 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-20 15:12:39.308  INFO 8772 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2016-06-20 15:12:39.310  INFO 8772 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-06-20 15:12:39.310  INFO 8772 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think there is something wrong with entity classes only . Please help me to define a correct model and create them automatically in mysql .

Comment: If anyone can tell me what should be the right DB schema for this mapping . In one way one to many & bidirectional many to one mapping .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Board> boards;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "board")
public class Board {
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "board")
    private Set<Card> cards;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
public class Card {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boardid")
    private Board board;

}
```

Comment: Bhashkar .. I've tried to map entities according to your approach also but there are 3 tables only .. i.e. user (userid, password , username) , Board (boardid, boardcreationdate, boardname, userid), Card (cardid, cardcreationdate, cardlife, cardtimeondone, cardname , boardid) .. I've a question here that in board and user tables there is no column for collection columns of boards and cards . .. Could you please tell me what should be the right schema . ..would be a great help ..

Comment: @hjain25 that's the correct schema :) As a thumb rule, remember that in 1 to M relationship, the primary key of 1's side goes to the Many's side as a (foreign key) column. That's why you see `boardid` in `Card` and `userid` in `Board`. The collections are actually virtual, hibernate fetches the many side into this collection based on the foreign key. So go with Anil's approach  Please read more about how relationships are resolved in JPA/Hibernate. It's a one time task - once you understand it, you won't forget for the rest of your life :)

Comment: @hjain25 It wont create a column in `User` table with list of `Board` values in db. Although your java object of `User` will have all the `Board` objects which are associated to it.

Comment: @hjain25 please accept answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves your error, but this looks invalid

```
 @OneToMany(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy = "boardname" , targetEntity = Board.class)
    private Set<Card> cards;
```

It should be

```
 @OneToMany(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy = "boardname" , targetEntity = Card.class)
    private Set<Card> cards;
```

Comment: @hjain25 check the import statement for `Card` in Boards.java. You seem to have imported `javax.smartcardio.Card`. You need to replace it with the correct path of Card entity

Comment: Yes I found this silly mistake of mine and corrected but ... I also want to be sure about the DB schema .. it is creating schema like this .  Board (boardid, boardcreationdate, boardname, userid),   board_cards(board_boardid, cards_id) ,  Card(cardid, cardcreationdate, cardlife, cardtimeondone, cardname, boardid),  User(userid, password, username) , user_boards(user_userid, boards_boardid).. I am not sure why it is creating a separate schema to link ids of two entities coz that is the case with Many to many mapping .. Please comment . Thanks .

Comment: Umm yes that schema looks incorrect. It shouldn't generate intermediate tables. That means your annotations are incorrect somewhere. Try this - remove `referencedColumnName` from all your `@JoinColumn` annotations. Also try Anil's approach above - it looks concise.

Comment: ,.. I tried removing `referencedColumnName` which did not change anything in the schema . .. and I've tried to map entities according to Anil's approach also but there are 3 tables only .. i.e. user (userid, password , username) , Board (boardid, boardcreationdate, boardname, userid), Card (cardid, cardcreationdate, cardlife, cardtimeondone, cardname , boardid) .. I've a question here that in board and user tables there is no column for collection columns of boards and cards . .. Could you please tell me what should be the right schema . ..would be a great help ..